# JPQL: OR won't work as expected

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, jpql

I have the following method defined in a Repository:

```
@Query("SELECT t FROM Treatment t WHERE " +
        " (t.promotionCode.promotion.id=:promotionId)  " +
        " order by t.id desc")
Page<Treatment> findByPromotionId(@Param("promotionId")Integer id, Pageable pr);
```

And it worked as expected: I got a list of Treatments that have a PromotionCode that belongs to a given Promotion.

But then I needed to add a second promotion code, so a Treatment can be linked to up to two Promotions (both promotion codes may belong to the same promotion, that is not an issue). So I tried to add the new requirement to the query:

```
@Query("SELECT t FROM Treatment t WHERE " +
            " (t.promotionCode.promotion.id=:promotionId)  " +
            " OR " +
            " (t.promotionCode2.promotion.id=:promotionId)  " +
            " order by t.id desc")
Page<Treatment> findByPromotionId(@Param("promotionId")Integer id, Pageable pr);
```

But I won't work. The generated SQL is

```
select ...
from treatment treatment0_ 
  cross join promotion_code promotionc1_ 
  cross join promotion_code promotionc2_ 
where 
  treatment0_.promotion_code_id=promotionc1_.id and
  treatment0_.promotion_code2_id=promotionc2_.id and 
  (promotionc1_.promo_id=? or promotionc2_.promo_id=?)
order by 
  treatment0_.id desc limit ?
```

As you can notice, as soon as one of the promotion codes is null, the condition is not fulfilled.

Some details, even if they are obvious from the code:

- Besides `treatment` there is a table named `promotion_code` and another one named `promotion`.
- All tables have a numeric ID (autoincremented).
- `promotion_code_id` and `promotion_code2_id` are FKs pointig at `promotion_code`, which also has a FK to `promotion` and it cannot be null (all promotion codes belong to a promotion).

I want to find all treatments that are linked to a promotion by any of the promotion code columns. Both fields may be null.

How can I solve this?

Comment: are you sure you are compiling properly and that the generated SQL is the method you posted ?? Otherwise there might be an issue with the `Treatment` entity and how you relate it to `PromotionCode`. Also , if you could try passing it as native sql and allow the mapper pass back `Page<Treatment>`

Comment: I'm sure about the compiling because I've tested checking only promotion_code and then only promotion_code2, I was thinking about `UNION`but it seems it is not  supported by JPQL

Comment: maybe you need to join promotion manually. Using `join fetch` or `left join fetch`. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28694929/jpql-join-fetch-on-a-table-with-nullable-columns)

Comment: @Patrick Thank you for the suggestion, I will try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to mimic the UNION, and it worked:

```
SELECT t
FROM Treatment t 
WHERE t IN (SELECT t FROM Treatment t 
      WHERE t.promotionCode.promotion.id = :promotionId)
  OR t IN (SELECT t FROM Treatment t
      WHERE t.promotionCode2.promotion.id = :promotionId)
ORDER BY t.id desc
```

Before that I tried the LEFT JOIN FETCH option with

```
SELECT t 
FROM Treatment t 
LEFT JOIN t.promotionCode.promotion as pc
LEFT JOIN t.promotionCode2.promotion as pc2
WHERE 
  (pc.id=:promotionId)  
OR (pc2.id=:promotionId)  
order by t.id desc
```

and with

```
SELECT t 
FROM Treatment t 
LEFT JOIN t.promotionCode as pc
LEFT JOIN t.promotionCode2 as pc2
WHERE 
  (pc.promotion.id=:promotionId)  
OR (pc2.promotion.id=:promotionId)  
order by t.id desc
```

but they did not work (I got long stack trace saying the query was not correct while starting the application),

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the criteria API.

The CriteriaBuilder interface provides factory methods that take two Expression operands (including Predicate instances) and return a new Predicate instance:

```
  Predicate p1 = cb.and(isInUN, isInEU);  // Member of both UN and EU
  Predicate p2 = cb.or(isInOECD, isLarge); // Either OECD member or large
```

Additional factory methods are available for a variant number of predicates:

```
  Predicate p3 = cb.and(p1, isLarge, cb.isTrue(isInOECD));
  Predicate p4 = cb.or(p2, cb.isTrue(isInUN), cb.isTrue(isInEU));
```

In the above code non Predicate boolean expressions are converted to Predicate instances using the isTrue method. This is required because in the non binary version the factory methods accept only Predicate instances as arguments.

source url: https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/logical#Criteria_Query_Logical_Operators_

Comment: My repository is just a interface, so I am trying to avoid this kind of solutions, but I will have it in mind just in case, thank you!